# git head is n commits behind master branch

Tags: git, netbeans, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Netbeans and Sourcetree on a bitbucket git repository. After a series of commits and branch creations, I got to this situation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x15PC.jpg]

All the commits between `HEAD` and `master` are mine, but every commit I have to merge the `master`?

I can't understand why `HEAD` is far behind `master`, why do I have to merge, and how do I get to a "normal" situation. If I try to commit and push from Netbeans, all I got as result is an error.

Comment: It seems you're in detached head state. Perhaps you should create a branch? Or perhaps you should merge with master to get HEAD and master in sync? I think the main problem here is that you don't understand what it means that HEAD is behind, and thus aren't able to formulate the question describing what you *want* to happen. If we don't know that, it's kinda hard to give you the right advice.

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is `git checkout master`?

Comment: To be honest, the view there looks confused. The circle next to master says "you're here, you've checked out master", yet HEAD is way behind, and HEAD is what points to what you've checked out, which is definitely not master.

Comment: I found a solution. I did a checkout from HEAD, and that operation removed some files from my working copy. Then I did a git pull to get all my files back, and finally the HEAD is where it's supposed to be.